# Aurelia - how to change a date-picker value with pure JS (from outside the Aurelia Framework)

Tags: javascript, datepicker, aurelia

I'm building automation function to fill in the form in Aurelia framework app. I'm doing it from outside the framework (pure JS). I can change the "input" field value and everything works fine.
But I don't know how to change the [date-range-picker] value. When I change the "input" value of this date-range-picker field - everything is OK on the screen but the date is not set (when I click the field -the popup datepicker shows default date).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is that I need some help from the person who know how to properly set the value on the date-range-picker field in Aurelia framework using pure JS. I don't have any code that could help.
I can set the value of all other inputs in Aurelia app with JS events: "change", "input" and "blur".